# Some doubts about the parameters of the savgol_filter function from scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, filtering, smoothing

I was reading the documentation of `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` from

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html

and I have doubts with the parameters `deriv` and `delta` defined in the extract below:

> **deriv** : int, optional
>
> The order of the derivative to compute. This must be a nonnegative
>   integer. The default is 0, which means to filter the data without
>   differentiating.
>
> **delta** : float, optional
>
> The spacing of the samples to which the filter will be applied. This
>   is only used if deriv > 0. Default is 1.0.

Regarding the parameter `deriv=0`: Does it mean that when `deriv=0` the function provides a smooth version of the **original** data and when `deriv=1` the function provides a smooth version of the **first derivative** of the original data?

Regarding the parameter `delta`: Does it mean that the function `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` only works for evenly sampled data?

Comment: FYI: Update your link; the latest released version of SciPy is 1.2.1: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the author of that code, I can definitively say: yes and yes.